# configure NodeJS process on two different machine

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have two different nodejs web app running on two different machine.

But I need to have one endpoint to user api1.abc.com/v1 to go one process and api2.abc.com/v2 go to another process.

how can i do this kind of request with the single endpoint to user (abc.com). need a nginx setup guide ?

I need this setup because internally I need to call user authenticated api from one server to another.

Answer (score 1):

On one server you need to receive the data (using express & router):

```
router.get('/v1', function(req, res) {
  // TODO
  res.render('something');
});
```

and on the other you need to fetch:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express()    

app.use('api1.abc.com', router);

router.post('/v1', function(req, res) {
  // process res
});
```

Comment: My Question is how can we configure NGINX for three services. Ex Do I need a separate NGINX server to map other two private ip servers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write code at version two apis. In request you can pass version on which you need to call.

Call all api's on version 2. If it required to call on second server. Write code on version one to identify the call from version 2. So that it can by pass the basic authentication.

Thanks,

Comment: My Question is how can we configure NGINX for three services. Ex Do I need a separate NGINX server to map other two private ip servers ?